# How to fadeup words each with a little delay to make a great headline

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

I want to make a headline on my website which would animate like one on this website: https://www.thisisbeyond.com/what-we-believe/
So I want the words to fade-up each with a little delay.
How could I do that? If it is possible with css only, that would be great. But javascript is also acceptable :)

I have tried splitting my words each into one column and then animating the columns (opacity: 0 to 1 transition), but it results in strange spacing between words AND I want them to fade-up, not only change the opacity. So I think the right way to do it is by just putting each word in a different span element and then animating the spans.

```
<h1 class="animated2">
<span>To</span> <span>show</span> <span>the</span> <span>power</span> <span>of</span> 
<span class="highlight">humanity&nbsp;</span>
<span class="highlight">in</span> 
<span class="highlight">business.</span>
</h1>
```

LINK to the website I am trying to achieve this: [michalkuczek.pl](https://michalkuczek.pl/nowa-strona-glowna/)

```
.highlight{
    background: #fff;
}
@keyframes fadeInUpSmall{
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform:translateY(10px)}
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform:translateY(0)}
}

.animated2 span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: .1s;
}

.animated2 span {
    animation-name: fadeInUpSmall;
}
.animated2 {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/webinspect/pen/WvGXEZ might help.

Comment: You can also look at CSS var, so only one rule can be written in the css sheet , but var is to be set iline https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNJZdO  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: If you are still having issues I would suggest referencing this: https://codepen.io/ahmmu15/pen/EVqWvz

Comment: Your missing a js lib which adds the fadein class to make the magic happen.
If you inspect the sitessource code and do a little googling on 'data-os-animation', im shure you'll find a tutorial

Comment: @JakeFromSF thank you, your link helped me to make the opacity animation, yet the movement up wasn't working until I found somewhere that the parent element to spans has to have a display: inline-block; css on it as well. Now it works, you can look: https://michalkuczek.pl/nowa-strona-glowna/

Comment: Great I will write an answer then so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the opacity animation by creating keyframes that define the start and end states.

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
  -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
  -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
  animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;
}

.fade-in.one {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.fade-in.two {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

.fade-in.three {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1.6s;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="animated2">
    <span>To</span> <span>show</span> <span>the</span> <span>power</span> <span>of</span>
    <span class="highlight fade-in one">humanity&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="highlight fade-in two">in</span> 
    <span class="highlight fade-in three">business.</span>
</h1>
```